# How to UNION ALL two CTE's with pivoted SELECT statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have two pivoted results of CTE and I need them to UNION ALL to receive result like that:
[image]

```
;WITH cte_yoyComparison
AS
            (
SELECT      b.YearNum,  
            b.MonthName,
            sum(Premium) as Premium 
            FROM tblCalendar b  
LEFT JOIN Test_Plaza_ProductionReport  a ON b.MonthNum=MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum=YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
WHERE       YEAR(EffectiveDate) <> 2017
GROUP BY    b.YearNum, 

            b.MonthName
            )
            ,
    cte_yoyComparison1
AS
        (
SELECT  b.YearNum,
        b.MonthName,
        ISNULL(sum(case when TransactionType IN ('Policy', 'Reinstatement') then 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as Bound--,   
FROM    tblCalendar b  LEFT JOIN Test_Plaza_ProductionReport  a ON b.MonthNum=MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum=YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
WHERE YEAR(EffectiveDate) <> 2017
GROUP BY    b.YearNum, 
            b.MonthName,
            b.MonthNum
            )

            select [YearNum] as [YearNum],
[January], [February],[March], [April],[May],[June],[July], [August], [September],[October],[November],[December]  from ( select * from cte_yoyComparison) src
PIVOT
    (
            sum(src.Premium)
            FOR src.[MonthName] IN ([January], [February],[March], [April],[May],[June],[July], [August], [September],[October],[November],[December])
    ) as [PivotTable]

UNION ALL 

select [YearNum] as [YearNum], 
[January], [February],[March], [April],[May],[June],[July], [August], [September],[October],[November],[December]  from ( select * from cte_yoyComparison) src
PIVOT
    (
            sum(Bound)
            FOR src.[MonthName] IN ([January], [February],[March], [April],[May],[June],[July], [August], [September],[October],[November],[December])
    ) as [PivotTable]
```

Im getting error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31 Incorrect syntax near ';'.

How would be the correct way to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: In my `SSMS` it got parsed

Comment: SQL Pivots are difficult to read and maintain. Consider having the SQL just return the raw data that you want and then use SSRS row and column groupings to render the tables dynamically.